# How to communicate peer to peer computers which are connected over wifi/lan in python with low latency?

Tags: python, data-transfer

I have two systems, one is connected over wifi, and another via lan to same network. I want a mechanism where I can transfer data securely/non-securely with low latency via python.

I am using mqtt here, `mqtt broker` + `mqtt publish and subscribe` on one system. 
`mqtt publish and subscribe` on another system.

Any better solution with any other protocol, would be of great help.